# Curve fitting to a set of data

Tags: fitting

I am trying to fit a polynomial to the data listed as

```
{{0,6.67},{6,17.33},{10,42.67},{13,37.33},{17,30.1},{20,29.31},{28,28.74}}.
```

When I use

```
LinearModelFit[data,{x,x^2,x^3,x^4,x^5,x^6},x]
```

I get

```
FittedModel[6.67-42.6435x+16.1427x^2-<<19>>x^3 +<<20>>x^4-0.00367168x^5 +0.0000409458x^6.
```

I don't understand why I am not getting any coefficients for the `x^3` and `x^4` terms that make sense and would like some assistance in solving this problem.

Comment: When you have ```fm = LinearModelFit[…]```, then you can query the coefficients like this: ```fm["BestFitParameters"]```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a severe case of overfitting

```
lmf = LinearModelFit[data, {x, x^2, x^3, x^4, x^5, x^6}, x]
Show[{ListPlot@data, Plot[lmf[x], {x, 0, 30}]}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]